# Finding voltage across inductor in steady state

Tags: voltage, inductor, steady-state

I am uncertain about the voltage drop I got across the inductor because of its extremely small magnitude compared to the voltage source. Was my procedure correct or were there any flaws in my calculations?[image]

Comment: @JRE 0 ohms, but the frequency in this case is 2500/2pi so how does that come into play?

Comment: Had a brain fart.  "Steady state" translated in my mind to "DC" and I missed the definition of Vs.

Comment: Now that you have \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$, calculate the current through all of the passive elements and verify that KCL works at all of the nodes. Or, calculate the voltage across all elements and use KVL to verify. Being able to check your own work is a very valuable skill.

Comment: @Hector I follow your logic with respect to the relationship of \$V_\text{B}\$ and \$V_\text{A}\$. I follow your KCL for \$V_\text{A}\$. I follow your value for \$V_\text{s}\$. But when I solve for \$V_\text{A}\$ I don't get your answer for it. I get closer to: \$V_\text{A}=\left(0.0014298 - j\,0.2121643\right)\,V_\text{s}\$.